# How to setup my htaccess file, all I get is a server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I downloaded a script called VieFaucet, however, I have run into some problems that I have narrowed down to the .htaccess file.

This is what I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

However, this brings me to a server error 500 and I am at a loss on what to do now.

Comment: Perhaps, `mod-rewrite` isn't enabled on your server. Check your `error.log` file to see the reason of 500 error.

Comment: I am using ionos and mod_rewrite is enabled, not sure how to get to my error log though

Comment: Are there any other directives in your htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was ioncube loader that was causing a problem, I have switched hosting as it kept spitting errors and now it works on the new host.